# Why is the text output from the center of the text box when the XMLHttpRequest is conducted?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, xmlhttprequest

I created the XHR in my page and got the answer from php file in a textarea. As a result, answer not to be displayed from the top of the textbox and right from the center. What should I do to get the answer printed from the beginning of the textarea? [My page with XHR here](https://mahorat.org/public/ajax.php) And one more problem with the speed of the request of the XHR. Is it possible to create something similar for instant processing and response. For example, like Google translate.

Code ajax.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Translator</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />

    <!-- Style Sheets -->

        <?php require_once("../resources/views/template/stylesheets.php"); ?>

    <!-- Style Sheets -->

    <script>(function(e,t,n){var r=e.querySelectorAll("html")[0];r.className=r.className.replace(/(^|\s)no-js(\s|$)/,"$1js$2")})(document,window,0);</script>
    <script>
    function response(str) {
        if (str.length == 0) { 
            document.getElementById("lang-output").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("lang-output").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };

            var body = "request=" + encodeURIComponent(str);
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "request.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", body.length);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            xmlhttp.send(body);
        }
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Loader -->

        <?php require_once("../resources/views/template/loader.php"); ?>

    <!-- Loader -->



    <!-- Main-Navigation -->



<?php require_once("../resources/views/template/AjaxMainNavigation.php"); ?>

    <!-- Main-Navigation -->



    <!-- Quick Translator -->

    <section id="quick-translator">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <h1 class="section-heading wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="0.5s">Дар матни Шумо хатогиҳо мавҷуд аст?</h1>
                <p class="section-desc wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="0.5s">
                    Он гоҳ ба шумо онлайн сервиси MAHORAT.ORG кӯмаки зуддии худро расонида, матнотонро дуруст месозад. 
                </p>
                <div class="section-seperator">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="translator">
                    <form class="translation-form">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">

                            <div class="language-area">
                                <textarea onkeyup="response(this.value)" class="form-control wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="0.5s" name="lang-input" id="lang-input" rows="10"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <p class="upload-info wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="0.5s" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                                Матнро ворид намоед ё суроғаи веб-сомонаро нависед ё ин ки
                                <input type="file" name="file-1" id="file-1" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
                                <label for="file-1"><span title="Боркунии файли беруна">Боркунии файли беруна</span></label>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">

                            <div class="language-area">
                                <textarea valign="top" class="form-control wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="0.5s" name="lang-output" id="lang-output" rows="10"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Quick Translator -->

    <!-- CopyRight -->

        <?php require_once("../resources/views/template/copyright.php"); ?>

    <!-- CopyRight -->

    <!-- Scripts -->

        <?php require_once("../resources/views/template/scripts.php"); ?>

    <script src="http://diplom.loc/resources/views/template/assets/js/typed.js"></script>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

          Typed.new('.incorrect', {
            strings: ["точики", "забони точики", "Точикистон", "Гайратчон", "Хаёт ба хар як шахс дар ин дунё як бор дода мешавад.","точики", "забони точики", "Точикистон", "Гайратчон", "Хаёт ба хар як шахс дар ин дунё як бор дода мешавад.","Мувафаккият барои шумо!"],
            typeSpeed: 230
          });

          Typed.new('.correct', {
            strings: ["тоҷикӣ", "забони тоҷикӣ", "Тоҷикистон", "Ғайратҷон", "Ҳаёт ба ҳар як шахс дар ин дунё як бор дода мешавад.","тоҷикӣ", "забони тоҷикӣ", "Тоҷикистон", "Ғайратҷон", "Ҳаёт ба ҳар як шахс дар ин дунё як бор дода мешавад.", "Мувафаққият барои шумо!"],
            typeSpeed: 250
          });""
      });      
    </script>

    <!-- Scripts -->

</body>
</html>
```

Code request.php

```
<?php include("../config/includes.php") ?>
<?
$request = $_REQUEST["request"];

$hint = "";

if ($request !== "") {

$uncorrect = $Helper->UncorrectUnique();

$correct = $Helper->CorrectUnique();

$dict = array_combine($uncorrect, $correct);

$hint = preg_replace_callback("/\pL+/u", function ($m) use ($dict) {
    $word = mb_strtolower($m[0]);
    if (isset($dict[$word])) {
        $repl = $dict[$word];
        // Check for some common ways of upper/lower case
        // 1. all lower case
        if ($word === $m[0]) return $repl;
        // 2. all upper case
        if (mb_strtoupper($word) === $m[0]) return mb_strtoupper($repl);
        // 3. Only first letters are upper case
        if (mb_convert_case($word,  MB_CASE_TITLE) === $m[0]) return mb_convert_case($repl,  MB_CASE_TITLE);
        // Otherwise: check each character whether it should be upper or lower case
        for ($i = 0, $len = mb_strlen($word); $i < $len; ++$i) {
            $mixed[] = mb_substr($word, $i, 1) === mb_substr($m[0], $i, 1) 
                ? mb_substr($repl, $i, 1)
                : mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($repl, $i, 1));
        }
        return implode("", $mixed);
    }
    return $m[0]; // Nothing changes
}, $request);

$hint = $Helper->specialCheck($hint);
}

echo $hint === "" ? "" : preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', $hint);

?>
```

Comment: its necessary to use text-area you can use div or input [text] instead

Comment: I changed my question @nnnnnn